# What creates eth0:avahi interface?

Tags: linux, networking

I've configured a VPN connection and it created `foo` interface listed with `ifconfig`. Its IP is assigned via `dhclient foo`.

From time to time, my connection drops. When I list the available interfaces with `ifconfig`, there is `foo` without an IP and `foo:avahi` with a random IP.

If I request an IP with `dhclient foo`, an IP (generally same IP) is immediately fetched, my internet connection is fixed and the `foo:avahi` interface is disappeared.

What is this `...:avahi` interface and how can I prevent this connection drops from happening?

Comment: Is other network configuration software, such as NetworkManager, running on your system?

Comment: No, NetworkManager is totally uninstalled. I'm using [my own network manager](https://github.com/aktos-io/aktos-nm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an interface; this is how old tools, namely ifconfig, show additional IP addresses on the `eth0` interface (the kernel emulates an "interface alias" for every extra address).

The address/alias marked with "avahi" is created by *avahi-autoipd*, which implements [RFC 3927](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927) IPv4 link-local address autoconfiguration (also known as [zeroconf or APIPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking#Address_selection)). The IP address isn't random; it's chosen from the reserved link-local prefix `169.254.0.0/16`.

As for why this appears on its own, you'll need to actually check the system logs to find out; autoipd could be both the cause of the problems or it could be just the result of external problems.

- It could be that some component in your system thinks no connection profile is active *yet* – because you've configured the IP address externally – so it deliberately switches into a "link-local only" profile and starts avahi-autoipd.
- It could be that you *first* lose the connection, the DHCP client loses its address lease and is unable to obtain a new one, and some component on your system switches to "link-local mode" as a last resort only.

Comment: If the reason was loosing the connection first, then could the "link-local mode" be interpreted as "Currently we have no IP"? If so, is it correct to re-issue `dhclient foo` to get a new IP or is it only a workaround for a different problem?